# Gradle War Plugin: creates an intermediate directory in project root

Tags: java, gradle, war

I have a Gradle project, which produces a .war file at the end of the build. It works great, except for one thing.

While building, the plugin creates a directory in the project root folder called `war`, which contains basically the exploded version of the end result.

I wouldn't be bothered by it, if it wasn't in my build directory, because this way, it looks awful and also, IntelliJ picks it up as a Web root, which is annoying.

In the documentation I think I found the `output` property, which seems like the one telling me where this folder is. The problem is that it's read-only, so I can't rewrite it to my liking.

Is there a way to put this directory elsewhere?
[Here](https://pastebin.com/b3dgsFnd) is a link to my `build.gradle` file

Comment: Could you post your `build.gradle`? Did you check the different [configuration properties](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.War.html) of the gradle war plugin?

Comment: I didn't find the parameter I'm looking for on that page. I included a link to the build.gradle file in the original post

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, that I falsely accused the Gradle War Plugin with creating that folder. In fact, it was the Gradle Gwt plugin